# How to use page-object style automation test inside a web application that doesn't change pages

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm currently using Ruby, Watir-webdriver, and Cucumber to create an automated testing framework. I really like the way the page-object style structures code but my application doesn't actually change pages very often (I'm trying to automate Sitecore Content Editor/Page Editor). I'm assuming there is a way to separate large portions of the page into it's own class and then define methods inside that class. However, how would I call this class using the page-object gem and cucumber if I need to do a lot on the same page?

So far the only way I know how to do this is like this.

```
class Sitecore
    include PageObject
    page_url "http://website.com/"
    include PageObject::PageFactory

    # methods for a large portion A
    # methods for a large portion B
    ...
    # methods for a large portion Z
end
```

Then have a corresponding Cucumber test like this.

```
Given(/^I am in the content editor$/) do
    visit Sitecore do |page|
        page.MethodA
        page.MethodB
    end
end

When(/^I navigate to some folder$/) do
        on Sitecore do |page|
            page.MethodC
            page.MethodD
        end
    end

Then(/^I should see something present$/) do
        on Sitecore do |page|
            page.MethodE
        end
    end
```

These are all using the same class so it's easy. I just use the visit and on keywords. But if I were to change this into multiple classes how do I call these without actually changing the page I am on?

Comment: It is a bit unclear where you are having difficulties. Why can you not create multiple page objects and use them like normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, are you looking for this:

```
Given(/^I am in the content editor$/) do
    page = Sitecore.new
    page.goto(page_url)
end

When(/^I navigate to some folder$/) do
    page.MethodC
    page.MethodD
end

Then(/^I should see something present$/) do
    page.MethodE
end
```

Comment: Yes I think this will work! Thanks! I think I was over thinking the issue

Comment: NP.. Keeping it simple is always the best way to go.